# Magento 2 get Product Collection creates issue on preparecollection

Tags: magento2, magento2.2, magento2.2.7

I am using Magento 2.2.7. On custom product grid `_prepareCollection()` I tried to get all product collection by

```
$collection = $this->_productFactory->create()->getCollection();
```

but it gets only `enabled` & `in_stock` products. If I get `count($collection->getData())` it shows all product count. but If I tried with `$collection->count()` it get only `enabled` and `in_stock` product count. How I get all products in grid through `$this->setCollection($collection);`

Comment: I think it is better to use `\Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory`

Comment: same it hides `out_of_stock` and `disabled` product. But why can you help in this regard?

Comment: I guess the stock status is your problem (disabled products are by default removed from stock). Check the SQL output of your collection and maybe this workaround would help you -> https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/13411 But as far as I know this limitation is added to product collection only in frontend and respects the configuration wheter to display out of stock products or not. I assume your code should run in admin area so the inventory plugin which affects the collection (`Magento\CatalogInventory\Model\AddStockStatusToCollection::beforeLoad()`) shouldn't be implied!